# Using alternative for Visual Studio for cmake

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, cmake

Actually my computer has a low space. That's the reason for taking an alternative of Visual Studio. I am trying to use the face-recognition library in python. As we know that cmake is a C-Based language. We also need to install a compiler too. So please help me by letting me know that :

- Whether there is an alternative of Visual Studio
- (If yes) then what is it.
- And how to install it

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of alternatives to Visual Studio, but first a quick clarification - Visual Studio is an IDE and it includes various compilers.

If you just need a compiler you can download the binaries from [gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and build on the command line.

If you want an IDE (but lighter than VS) I'd recommend CodeBlocks, which you can download from [codeblocks.org](http://www.codeblocks.org).

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again, but i am getting confused to install the compiler from https://www.gcc.gnu.org if possible, kindly please give me the steps too please :)

Comment: It was a mistake to refer you to the gcc website - I haven't actually tried it myself and it is not not as simple as I thought. The easiest way is to use codeblocks - this will download an appropriate compiler for you as part of the installation process. Note that the compiler itself takes 0.5 GB of space.
Here is a detailed [guide how to install it using codeblocks](https://www.guru99.com/c-gcc-install.html)